# Cannot Resolve 'function' object has no attribute '_default_manager'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I've been struggling with this all day, I already implemented the CreateView and it works fine, now that I'm trying to do the Update with the UpdateView (CBV) I'm getting this error:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/drivers/edit/2/
Django Version: 3.0.2
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'function' object has no attribute '_default_manager' Exception
Location:   C:\Users\jorge.lopez\.virtualenvs\Carros-ZVuxKBiy\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\detail.py
in get_queryset, line 67 Python
Executable: C:\Users\jorge.lopez\.virtualenvs\Carros-ZVuxKBiy\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.3
```

**complete traceback:**
[http://dpaste.com/3Z7YFMD]

*model.py*

```
class conductores(models.Model):

    nombres = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    apellidos = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    edad = models.IntegerField()
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(
        regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed.")
    # validators should be a list
    telefono = models.CharField(
        validators=[phone_regex], max_length=17, blank=True)
    ine = models.FileField(upload_to='INE/', blank=True, null=True)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('nombres', 'apellidos')
        verbose_name_plural = "Conductores"

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.nombres, self.apellidos)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('conductores')
```

*urls.py*

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    # path('conductores_sort/',
    #      views.conductores_sort.as_view(), name='conductores_sort'),
    path('conductores_list/', views.conductores),
    path('drivers/', views.ConductoresListView.as_view(), name='conductores'),
    path('drivers/add/', views.ConductoresCreate.as_view(), name='conductor_new'),
    path('drivers/edit/<int:pk>/',
         views.ConductoresUpdate.as_view(), name='conductor_edit'),
]
```

*views.py*

```
class ConductoresCreate(CreateView):
    form_class = PostConductores
    template_name = "AC/add_driver.html"


class ConductoresUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = conductores
    fields = ('nombres', 'apellidos', 'telefono', 'edad', 'ine')
```

Comment: It's better practice in python terms to call your model `Conductores`. Case is important for readability & writing sensible code. This looks especially important because you have a view which is imported to `urls.py` as `views.conductores` but you also import `conductores` in `views.py` as the model class for the `ConductoresUpdate` so they will clash. Also you'll need to post the full stacktrace because the error you've shared only details a line in a django function, not in your code.

Comment: ahh I get it (talking about the clash), I'm currently trying to rename the model, but I'm getting some errors. I'm editing the question to post the complete traceback.Thanks!

Comment: @markwalker_ turns out you were correct about the naming of models, I changed the case and it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better practice in python terms to call your model `Conductores`.

Case is important for readability & writing sensible code. This looks especially important because you have a view which is imported to `urls.py` as `views.conductores` but you also import `conductores` in `views.py` as the model class for the `ConductoresUpdate`, so they will clash.

For further reading on this, python has a style guide called PEP8. The Naming Conventions are detailed here; https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions

There's a slightly quicker read on the same message here; https://visualgit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/naming_convention.html